# Does AWS getSessionToken return the same credentials if called multiple times?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

How does AWS handle more than one call to getSessionToken? I was expecting it to return new access tokens, however it looks like it might use a previously generated one if still within a certain time range.

There doesn't appear to be any information on this in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html). I am specifically calling getSessionToken through the AWS SDK for PHP, but I don't think this matters.

```
$sts = StsClient::factory(
    // pass config here
);

$sessionToken = $sts->getSessionToken();
ECHO $sessionToken['Credentials'];

$sessionToken = $sts->getSessionToken();
ECHO $sessionToken['Credentials']; // Will the credentials be the same?
```

Comment: Is this just out of curiosity?  Your code shouldn't assume anything about the token that isn't documented so can't you  just treat it as a black box?

Answer (score 1):

Each execution of `getSessionToken` will not only result in **new token**, but also in new access and secret keys.

Please double check the your outputs. The tokens may look similar, but they should be different.

Comment: The question says that @user3750325 is getting the same token in their 2 adjacent PHP calls.  It's possible that Amazon's PHP library is responsible though (caching) and not AWS itself.

Comment: @DaveS The question is general in my view "Does AWS getSessionToken return the same credentials if called multiple times?" The OP should double check the token. it may look similar, but it should be different.